# PHPExcel - adding template in multiple sheets

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm trying to add template in multiple sheets with phpexcel:

```
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

//Start adding next sheets
$i=0;
while ($i < 10) {
  $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
  $objPHPExcel = $objPHPExcel->load('template.xlsx'); // Empty Sheet
  $objWorkSheet = $objPHPExcel->createSheet($i); //Setting index when creating

  //Write cells
  $objWorkSheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello'.$i)
               ->setCellValue('B2', 'world!')
               ->setCellValue('C1', 'Hello')
               ->setCellValue('D2', 'world!');

  // Rename sheet
  $objWorkSheet->setTitle("$i");

  $i++;
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. I only get two sheets, sheet with template and sheet with "9" title

So this is the result (sheet titles[image]):

[Sheet1 9](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rA9e4.png)

Comment: move these two lines above your loop $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
  $objPHPExcel = $objPHPExcel->load('template.xlsx');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PHPSpreadhsheet. This is what the currently deprecated PHPExcel library has been continued as.

Include the library in your .php file in the following way -

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();

?>
```

You can set title by adding-

```
$spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('A1','Hello');

$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('new');
$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);

$filename = 'XXX';

header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'. $filename .'.xls"'); 
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$writer->save('php://output');
```